# How to convert a String arrayList elements to a String Variables.?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, bluej

I created an arrayList of type String in the class Demo as follows:

```
protected ArrayList<String> stringList;

public Demo()
{
 stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

In the other class called client, I created an object of class Demo, so I can access the arrayList:

```
Demo d; 

public Client()
{
 b = new Demo();
}
```

another method called send message which exists in the Client class requires a parameters of type String. I invoked the send message and I gave the string arrayList as a parameters parameter but I keep getting an error as the type of the parameter is not a String.

```
sendMessage(b.stringList );
```

So, is there a way of storing the arrayList elements into String variables so they can be used within the sendMessage method.

Comment: Depends on the usecase. You can get String simply by calling `toString()` on stringList.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call toString method on your list to pass array list as a string.

So instead of:

```
sendMessage(b.stringList );
```

Use:

```
sendMessage(b.stringList.toString());
```

By doing so, you are creating a new String object everytime (taking a snapshot of whatever is there in list at that point of time) when you try to call sendMessage api and would not reflect any changes that you would do in your String list post passing on that string object to sendMessage api until you call sendMessage again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to call `sendMessage()` on each element of `b.stringList`, but you should clarify this. In that case, you can iterate through:

```
for (String element : b.stringList) {
    sendMessage(element);
}
```

Or, on Java 8, simply

```
b.stringList.forEach(this::sendMessage); // Assuming sendMessage is a method of 'this'.
```

If you want a string representation of the list, an `ArrayList` does have a `toString` method, but if you want compatibility with `List`s in general, write your own method to convert to a `String`, use a library or use `new ArrayList<>(yourList).toString()` (not recommended, as you must create new objects).